# "X has a strong appeal for Y". Does that mean X likes Y or the other way around?

Tags: meaning

I found this in the context of a randomly generated quote. I'm not a native speaker, and this nuance confuses me.

Could someone clarrify what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means Y likes X (Y finds X appealing).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I'll verify this though, but I trust you :D

Answer (score 1):

Y likes X, it is actually easier to put some words in.

This property has strong appeal for first home buyers. 
Chocolate has a strong appeal for me.